# How can I run a python script from within Flask

Tags: python, flask

I have a `Flask` script which creates a website and prints some data dynamically. - The data which it prints should come from another python script.

The current problem that I'm facing is that if I put the line that executes the python script before the line that executes the `Flask` app, it will run the Python script without running `Flask`; and vice versa.

Python script:

```
import websocket
from bitmex_websocket import Instrument
from bitmex_websocket.constants import InstrumentChannels
from bitmex_websocket.constants import Channels
import json

websocket.enableTrace(True)

sells = 0
buys = 0


channels = [
    InstrumentChannels.trade,
]


XBTUSD = Instrument(symbol='XBTUSD',
                    channels=channels)
XBTUSD.on('action', lambda msg: test(msg))


def test(msg):
    parsed = json.loads(json.dumps(msg))


    print(parsed)

XBTUSD.run_forever()
```

Flask script (NB: price should be the variable 'parsed' from the other script):

```
# Start with a basic flask app webpage.
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, copy_current_request_context
from random import random
from time import sleep
from threading import Thread, Event
import requests, json
import time

__author__ = 'slynn'

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
app.config['DEBUG'] = True

#turn the flask app into a socketio app
socketio = SocketIO(app)

#random number Generator Thread
thread = Thread()
thread_stop_event = Event()

class RandomThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        self.delay = 1
        super(RandomThread, self).__init__()

    def randomNumberGenerator(self):
        while not thread_stop_event.isSet():
            socketio.emit('newnumber', {'number': parsed}, namespace='/test')
            sleep(self.delay)

    def run(self):
        self.randomNumberGenerator()


@app.route('/')
def index():
    #only by sending this page first will the client be connected to the socketio instance
    return render_template('index.html')

@socketio.on('connect', namespace='/test')
def test_connect():
    # need visibility of the global thread object
    global thread
    print('Client connected')

    #Start the random number generator thread only if the thread has not been started before.
    if not thread.isAlive():
        print("Starting Thread")
        thread = RandomThread()
        thread.start()

@socketio.on('disconnect', namespace='/test')
def test_disconnect():
    print('Client disconnected')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app)
```

Comment: Please introduce some of the code, you've tried so far. Also, you can use `subprocess.call(["python","scriptname.py"], shell=true)` to run a script in background while running another script.

Comment: I added the code, in order to be more specific!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Using `import`:

- Wrap what the python script (e.g. `website_generator.py`) is generating into a function.
- Place it in the same directory as your `app.py` or `flask.py`.
- Use `from website_generator import function_name` in `flask.py`
- Run it using `function_name()`

You can use other functions such as `subprocess.call` et cetera; although they might not give you the response.

Example using `import`:

```
from flask import Flask
import your_module # this will be your file name; minus the `.py`

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def dynamic_page():
    return your_module.your_function_in_the_module()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port='8000', debug=True)
```

Comment: I tried that too but for some reason it will still run one of the two parts before the other, i have no idea why, i'm trying again right now! I added my code

Comment: I dont see any import from your module; what are you trying to achieve? where is the content generated? and where is it going to be used?

Comment: If you're actually calling `test` function; then you must `return` and not `print`.

Comment: You don't see the import because i changed it after it wasn't working, to test other ways. The expected output is to have the data from XBTUSD.run_forever printed on the webpage in real time with asincronous updates

Comment: Sorry for not being specific! What i'm trying to achieve is to have the parsed data from test printed on my webpage. My main two problems are the one i specified in my question and that i can't call the variable "parsed" from a different function

Comment: Why don't you make use of a `Queue` instead of calling `lambda`? and you could simply share the queue.

Comment: Well i'm fairly new to Python, i've never used Queue yet, but i'm now looking into it! I think the problem, though, is with the line of code XBTUSD.run_forever

Comment: I don't have access to see what's `Instrument` to be honest, but let me build you an example of how to use sockets easily with a Queue and without a Queue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181949/discussion-between-julian-camilleri-and-jack022).

Answer (score 5):

try this:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def run_script():
    file = open(r'/path/to/your/file.py', 'r').read()
    return exec(file)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```