# Start a background process with flask, then detects when it stops

Tags: python, flask, subprocess

I have a flask server and I'm trying to run a script in the background to enable a pairing process on a raspberry pi. I have a button to enable and disable this which works fine.

I use `process = subprocess.Popen(["python3","bt.py"])` to run the process then `process.kill()` when I need to stop it.

But once the task stops I need to update the page with the new device information, but I'm having trouble detecting when the pairing script stops via flask. I know I can run `process.poll()` to check if the subprocess is still running but I can't think of any way to implement this into flask as it would need to run in a loop, which would stop the client from receiving the page.

The only thing I think could work would be to edit a file from the `bt.py` script and have the JS part of my flask app detect the change in the file and cause a redirect. However, this seems clunky and feels like bad practice. Any suggestions would be great

Comment: It sounds like what you may need is a task queue. Some options here are Celery, RabbitMQ or Redis. Here is [a helpful blog post](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/using-celery-with-flask) you can use to get started.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I run a python script from within Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52835681/how-can-i-run-a-python-script-from-within-flask)

Comment: I’ll look into a task queue. Also that post does not answer my question, as it does not require the script to be continuously running. The script I’m trying to run needs to run in a while loop for about 30 seconds